# How to reference the most recent git commit whose commit message contains a certain word?

Tags: git

I want to do

```
$ git log - 5
*  adc24eb Jim > (HEAD -> demo) fixup
*  cb6a1a7 Jim > fixup
*  60d7150 Jim > (origin/demo) Much prettier demo output.
*  a8112c2 Michael > Complete ugly demo:
```

and then do some operations with `a8112c2`.  Rather than referencing that commit by SHA, as in

```
$ git <command> a8112c2
```

, I want to type things like

```
$ git rebase -i %ugly
$ git show %ugly
$ git reset --soft %ugly
```

where %ugly is expanded by git to the SHA of the most recent commit whose commit message first line contains the word "ugly".

**What's the magic syntax for this?**

I'm 99% sure this has been asked before and I cannot find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`man git-rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) is your friend. It looks like you want:

```
   :/<text>, e.g. :/fix nasty bug
       A colon, followed by a slash, followed by a text, names a commit
       whose commit message matches the specified regular expression. This
       name returns the youngest matching commit which is reachable from
       any ref. The regular expression can match any part of the commit
       message. To match messages starting with a string, one can use e.g.
       :/^foo. The special sequence :/!  is reserved for modifiers to what
       is matched.  :/!-foo performs a negative match, while :/!!foo
       matches a literal !  character, followed by foo. Any other sequence
       beginning with :/!  is reserved for now.
```

So for example:

```
git show :/ugly
```

Comment: Or, more directly, [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)